# This filters in memory right?

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I Just want to make sure I understand this correctly...

`search` is an object that contains a querystring.

`Repo.Query` returns an `ObjectQuery<T>`.

From my understanding the chained linq statements will filter the results after entity framework has returned all the rows satisfying the query. So really ALL the rows are being returned and THEN filtered in memory. So we are returning a bunch of data that we don't really want. There's about 10k rows being returned so this is kind of important. Just like to get my confusion cleared up.

```
var searchQuery = Repo.Query(search)
                .Where(entity =>
                        entity.Prop1.ToUpper().Equals(prop1.ToUpper()) &&
                        entity.Prop2.ToUpper().Equals(prop2.ToUpper()))
                .OrderBy(entity => Repo.SortExpression ?? entity.prop1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Repo.Query(string query)` function should return `IQueryable<T>`.

Then you can filter and order without getting all rows first.

[IQueryable(Of T) Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb351562.aspx)

**hope this helps**

Answer (score 1):

If this is to SQL, this will most likely create a SQL query and filter on the server and not in memory.

As a matter of fact, the statement above wouldn't actually do anything.
It's only when you iterate over it that the query will be executed. This is why certain providers (like the EF to SQL one) can collapse expression trees into a SQL query.

Easiest way to check is to use LINQPAD or the SQL Profiler to see what query is actually is executed.

Comment: Ok... Well its to Oracle using Devart.. But if I debug and do a `searchQuery.Count()` (omitting the where clause) I see 10k items. And of course when I run the `where` clause it filters it to the 3k rows I want. Haha I keep confusing myself, I'll see what I can find for tools to see whats actually happening I guess.